# Neovim Display Artefacts/Bug

Tags: neovim

I am trying to set up neovim on a remote machine (accessed by ssh) and while doing so I noticed visual artefacts, especially across windows when using visual mode line selection. For example, with a visual line select on the right window, bleeds into the left window.

And if I perform visual selection in a single window, it seems to skip the end of line character and other such display bugs.

[image: Visual artefact]

If I hit <C+l> this clears up the artefacts. Like so:

[image: Normal]

Some things that may be relevant:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Would appreciate any debugging tips or help! Thanks

Comment: tmux uses left/right margins (part of xterm for about ten years, but probably not supported by whatever your local terminal happens to be).

Comment: @ThomasDickey I'm not using tmux, were you referring to something else?

Comment: sorry - I misread that.  Still, worth checking left/right margins, because neovim uses those also.  In either case, if the margins don't work, the program can be confused about where the updates happen on the screen.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I am not sure which left/right margins you are referring to though - do you mean the terminal margins?

Comment: sure - look for `DECLRMM`